# Verifying Flash Player debug version installed: Is there a webpage that purposefully causes a Flash exception?

Tags: flash, debug

I need a quick way to verify that the Flash Player debug version is properly installed. I'm thinking that a page that has a flash widget embedded that tries to do `x=1/0;`... Basically I just want to see the debug dialog open so I know it's installed properly.

Does such a page exist?

Let me beat you to it:

> All Flash-based sites!

Now that that's out of the way...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this page? http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/
There is a small box that tells you what version is currently installed and active in the browser you are using.

Comment: I have. It does show the version number, but not whether it is the debug player or not, as far as I can see...